# Can pricing be trademarked?

Tags: trademark

[This earlier question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37775/can-pricing-be-copyrighted) asked whether a pricing scheme could be copyrighted.  I wonder if pricing could be trademarked.

Suppose Christopher Columbus Pizza was famous for selling a large pizza for $14.92.  Can they obtain a trademark on $14.92 to prevent competitors from also advertising their pizzas for the same price and confusing customers as to the quality or source?

Answer (score 4):

### **No**

An actual price is merely descriptive, amd cannot be a trademark, any more that "computer" can be for a PC.

A phrase including a price could be a trademark. Once upon a time, Pepsi used the slogan "Twice as much for a nickel too" which ws, or may have been, a trademark. They hypothetical Christopher Columbus Pizza could use a phrase such as 'A new world of flavor for only $14.92", but not, I think, the price alone.